# Match two strings on the basis of words only neglecting some special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match the two strings which contains different special characters like (-,:;) but the words are same. 
Eg. String 1 --> Hi, How are you?
String 2 --> Hi- How are you.

in the above example strings the words are same but only difference is in (,?-.).

So I want to know how I match these strings so that i get the answer "Strings are equal".

Comment: Perhaps remove everything besides alphabetical characters?

Comment: I won't show you a full solution, there are many options. One solution is simply replacing these characters with empty char, then compare the Strings.. Check [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: The 1st string i am getting is from my database so i cannot remove anything from that.

Comment: but you can make a copy of it and remove from that one.

Comment: You don't have to update the db with the replaced string. You can  replace strings read from the db and just ignore it after comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    boolean res = s1.replaceAll("[\\W]", "").equals(s2.replaceAll("[\\W]", ""));
```